# Editorlist plugin view in eclipse 4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

With eclipse 3.*, I used to have very convenient plugin called editorlist which showed up all the open editors.

I mainly used it to commit changes as it is much more convenient to select all files from this list rather than finding them in Naivigator or use the sync view, since the project is large and "svn update" takes some time. This plugin doesn't work on eclipse 4.

Is there simething similar in eclipse 4 for this?

Comment: Does the editorlist plugin work on Eclipse 4.2 (the SDK based on Eclipse 4)?

Comment: I checked it with 4.1 - will also check with 4.2